# How to use Char and VarBinary in Dapper?

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-extensions

I have to call Stored Procedure in which parameters are `char` and `VarBinary(MAX)`. I need to call this stored procedure from C# code using Dapper. But I am not able to find any parameter supported by dapper.

**SP:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspTest]      
 , @Param1   CHAR(1)        
 , @Param2   VARBINARY(MAX)=null
```

**C#:**

```
DynamicParameters parameter = new DynamicParameters();
parameter.Add("@Param1", email.SenderType, DbType.char, ParameterDirection.Input);
parameter.Add("@Param2", email.AttachedFileStream, DbType.varbinary, ParameterDirection.Input);
```

**Compilation Error:**

> DBType does not contain definition for char and varbinary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem doesn't have anything to do with Dapper, you're attempting to access enum members that simply don't exist.

The [`DbType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dbtype?view=netcore-3.1) enum does not contain members named `char` or `varbinary`.

Instead of `char` use `AnsiStringFixedLength` and instead of `varbinary` use `Binary`.
Also, at least in the first parameter, you should also include the size:

```
DynamicParameters parameter = new DynamicParameters();
parameter.Add("@Param1", email.SenderType, DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength, ParameterDirection.Input, 1);
parameter.Add("@Param2", email.AttachedFileStream, DbType.Binary, ParameterDirection.Input);
```

Comment: And for byte array `byte[]`, it whould be `DbType.Binary`.

Comment: @EmreBener That's correct, as you can see in Configuring parameters and parameter data types, in the [Specifying parameter data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#specifying-parameter-data-types) paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this;

```
db.Execute("Sql Query", new Dapper.DynamicParameters(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "ColumnName", "ValueObject" } }));
```

You must use variable type on Enum, like this;

public enum TestEnum : byte { // Values }